# Skipping UTC conversion in ActiveRecord with legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, utc, legacy, localtime

I am working with a Ruby on Rails application that makes use of multiple databases for integrating between legacy applications.

The Rails app itself has it's own database with DateTime stored in UTC, as is default. The legacy databases store their time in local time.

I need to read and store the legacy ActiveRecord models in local time, while still using `config.time_zone = 'Europe/Oslo'` in `application.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up overriding some ActiveRecord::Timestamp methods. I wrote my own Timestamp module that I included in the models needing to read and store data in local time.

```
class CustomerOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Timestamp
end

module Timestamp
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes << :LastUpdate
    skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes << :Created
  end

  private

  def current_time_from_proper_timezone
    Time.now + Time.now.utc_offset
  end

  def timestamp_attributes_for_update
    [:LastUpdate]
  end

  def timestamp_attributes_for_create
    [:Created]
  end

end
```